# Don't display the element in xml if its id attribute is null

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a xsd where there are 2 complextype elements under `<Customer>` complextype. One is `<NormalCustomer>` and `<PrivilegedCustomer>`. In my xml, I want either Normal or Privileged customer to be present under `<Customer>` tag based on the **id** attribute of Normal/Privileged customers.

below is my xsd

```
<xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="normalCustomer" type="tns:normalCustomer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
        <xs:element name="privilegedcustomer" type="tns:privilegedcustomer" minOccurs="0" nillable="true"/>
</xs:choice>
```

***Complextype NormalCustomer***

```
<xs:complexType name="normalCustomer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="customerType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

***Complextype PrivilegedCustomer***

```
<xs:complexType name="privilegedCustomer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="customerName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="customerType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**Note:**   Am using JAXB for processing

Please suggest me how can I modify the  tag to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `minOccurs="0" nillable="true"` from both elements. The `<xs:choice>` enforces that *exactly* one of the elements are present. If none present are allowed, add `minOccurs="0"` to `<xs:choice>`.

Comment: Can you help me in understanding how `choice` tag enforces only either of the elements present like, what is the decision factor that helps `choice` tag in taking decision ?

Comment: There is no "decision". When validating the XML according to the Schema, *exactly* one of the elements inside the `<choice>` is allowed.

Comment: everywhere I see the same thing like either of them will be present. if there is no decision, how only one element will be displayed. If this is the case, every time only the first element in choice tag should be present right ? sorry, I might be putting some basic questions.

Comment: Are you reading the XML, or writing the XML? If reading, then only one will be *present*. If writing, *you* choose which to use when populating the JAXB model. Have you even *looked* at the generated JAXB classes to see how you're accessing the data?

Comment: Am doing both reading the xml and generating xml based on the xsd. Can you point me to specific resources which can help me in understanding this. I am not very much familiar with Jaxb.

Comment: Let me ask again: "Have you looked at the generated JAXB classes?". If you did, you'd see that the `Customer` class has two members: `normalCustomer` and `privilegedCustomer`. When reading, *only one* of these will have a value. When write, *you* decide which of them gets assigned a value.

Comment: I didn't see the genereated JAXB classes. My application is very complex and I have no clue how and where to look for them. Very glad if you can help me in finding them.

Comment: Not knowing your *very complex* code, how could I. Look for code that creates a `Marshaller` and calls `m.marshal()`.

Comment: sorry for that, below is my method that calls marshall() method      \n                      `DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

  JAXBElement<PayLoad> customerTypeElement = (new ObjectFactory())
    .createPayLoad(source);
  Document doc;
  try {
   doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
   this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
     Boolean.TRUE);
   this.marshaller.marshal(customerTypeElement, doc);`